# Spring controller not able to resolve Thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

The controller class is not able to resolve any path except the root.
I have tried putting simple html code in index.html but controller couldn't resolve it. Contoller is able to resolve only this part

```
 @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
```

Controller code:

```
package com.controller;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.userFront.domain.User;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(Model model) {
        User user = new User();

        model.addAttribute("user", user);

        return "signup";
    }
//  
}
```

pom.xml code: I hope some dependancies are not missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.userFront</groupId>
    <artifactId>userFront</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>userFront</name>
    <description>User front for online banking app</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Code for index.html:

I have tried putting basic html code but wasn't successful in resolving it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head th:replace="common/header :: common-header"/>
<body>
<!-- Login Section -->
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/banner.png" alt="banner"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="main-center ">
                <div class="bg-danger" th:if="${param.error}">
                    Invalid username and secret.
                </div>
                <div class="bg-danger" th:if="${param.logout}">
                    You have been logged out.
                </div>
                <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/index}" method="post">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" roleId="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username"
                               id="username"
                               required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" roleId="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                               id="password"
                               name="password" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="remember-me"/> &nbsp; Remember me
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>

                <hr />

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <a type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block login-button" th:href="@{/signup}">Sign up!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div th:replace="common/header :: body-bottom-scripts"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some of the configuration missed in your pom.xml and configuration level, follow the below steps hope this will help.
1. **pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        .....
    </plugins>
</build>
```

2. **Templates:** resources folder path

> src/main/resources/templates/index.html

3. **Controller:** Not require to redirect

   `@GetMapping({"/", "/index"})
   public String index() {
       return "index";
   }`

Comment: I can see the page when I go the root page,  but when I try http://localhost:8080/index, it gives a 404 error.



The path is: /userFront/src/main/resources/templates/index.html